# fatal:remaining connection slots are reserver for non-replication superuser connections AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, psql

I have the below issue with my AWS RDS PostgreSql instance.

**fatal:remaining connection slots are reserver for non-replication superuser connections AWS RDS**

The solution is to kill all the idle connections and increase the max connection size.
But the challenge is, I could not even access the database due to the issue so that I can query and kill the idle sessions.

Any suggestion would be helpful to resolve the issue without accessing the database or wanted to know is there any other approach to access the database and kill the sessions.

Comment: Does the RDS interface not provide a way to do that through it (which would presumably go through superuser connections).

Comment: Hey!  Do you have a connection pool installed like pgBouncer?